# What exactly is the point of specifically 'inverting' buck/boost converters?

Tags: voltage-regulator, inverter, efficiency, buck-boost

I'm planning on generating a negative voltage for a circuit i'm working on, and want to use an inverting buck topology to do this. With the application being battery powered, my primary concern is efficiency.

Whilst looking at the many options available, I've come across parts that are marketed specifically as inverting regulators (such as the TPS63700). Considering that a normal buck converters can be modified very simply to become inverting regulators, what is the point of these parts? I would guess that its because the parts deal more specifically with the design considerations of adapting to a inverting topology (such as the need for wider input voltage ranges), but its just a guess.

Going back to my application... since I've found very high efficiency (~95%) buck converters that seem like they could be adapted to my application easily, should i just use them instead of these specifically 'inverting' regulators that generally have 10% lower efficiency (because the product pool is smaller)?

Comment: you did not say whether you are also generating a positive voltage ... are you?

Comment: I will be in relatively unrelated parts of the circuit. A few regulators will run from the battery. Though, if this regulator generated a -2V output, it does not imply that there would also need to be a +2V output required for another section of the circuit.

Comment: those were not my thoughts ... you may have an obscure circuit that is designed as being powered by a negative voltage without any positive voltages being used  ... in that case you could use a positive power supply and just use the `+` terminal as the ground for your circuit

Comment: Ah i see what you mean. I don't think i can do that coz the positive voltages will be used in part for biasing (relative to the negative voltage). The negative voltage I am generating is a cathode driving/biasing voltage for a VFD display. Elsewhere I will be boosting the battery voltage about 5x to ~19V for the anode biasing voltage. The idea behind generating the negative voltage is so i can save some efficiency in the boost converter by needing to boost it by about 5V less.

Comment: What is the simple modification you are planning to convert a positive buck into a negative one? I have seen this attempted and there was some non obvious  gotchas that made It not so simple. For example, the feedback may become positive if you invert the topology. Please post a schematic and a switcher part number

Comment: This document explains the concept quite well: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt286/slyt286.pdf. There are certainly 'gotchas' that make it less simple than a standard configuration, but if I can improve the performance of my circuit then i'm happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since I've found very high efficiency (~95%) buck converters that seem
>   like they could be adapted to my application easily, should i just use
>   them instead of these specifically 'inverting' regulators that
>   generally have 10% lower efficiency (because the product pool is
>   smaller)?

You may have found a buck regulator that is 95% efficient but this will undoubtedly be a synchronous buck converter that has an in-built MOSFET to replace the normally external diode. If it has an in-built MOSFET or diode then you can't use it to create a negative voltage.

Use an inverting type for simplicity - that's what they are designed for and, if you haven't found one with low enough internal power dissipation keep looking. It might help your cause if you state what power losses you can suffer, what input volage range you have and what output voltage and peak currents you expect.

---

Added section to give some insight into an inverting converter's efficiency.

[image]

When the input supply is connected to the inductor there is no transfer of energy to the output i.e. the output capacitor has to provide all the load current. There is only energy transfer when the input supply is disconnected by the switch and the inductor reverses its terminal voltage to circulate current into the storage capacitor and load.

Compare this with a buck converter; When the switch closes, current passes through the inductor to the capacitor and load thus simultaneously charging the inductor and providing current to the output. When the switch opens, current remains circulating through the inductor AND the capacitor/load.

This ultimately means that a buck converter can more efficiently deliver power to a given load because the charging currents are slightly less and the \$I^2R\$ losses are reduced.

Comment: Looking back on the various parts i wrote down, they indeed have built-in MOSFETs and no diode shown in their example application schematics. I feel stupid for not noticing this before. I'll still do think though that the best inverters i've found generally have lower efficiency than regular bucks with external diodes. I'll return with examples.

Comment: If you are asking why an inverting regulator is slightly less efficient than a non-synchronous buck converter I'll add to my answer shortly.

Comment: Looking at all the best parts for my application, I could only see buck converters without external diodes! Didn't notice that before. Here are some example efficiency estimates for a ~4V input voltage...
Diode-less buck converters, +2.5V@60mA:
TPS62205 - 95%,
TPS62120 - 95%,
NCP1529 - 95%,
TPS62000 - 93%,
TPS63030 - 90%,
TPS62240 - 90%,
LTC3410 - 90%,
Inverting regulators, -2.5V@60mA:
ADM8660 - 88%,
TPS60401 - 85%,
MAX764 - 82%,
LTC1983 - 80%,
MAX1673 - 80%,
TPS63700 - 75%,
LT1617 - 74%,
LT3483 - 72%,
LMR70503 - 70%,

Comment: And thanks for the added explanation about inverting vs buck topologies!